# Route all traffic from one interface (default gateway) through OpenVPN / tun0 - policy based routing, dependent on source address/interface

Tags: routing, openvpn, iproute, tunneling, gateway

I have a Debian Linux VPN router `myvpnserver` with 2 interfaces, `eno1` and `eno2`:

- `eno1` is connected to a LAN and an internet router. On this interface with static IP address, `myvpnserver` has its default gateway (to the Internet). OpenVPN connects to a VPN server using this internet connection.
- `eno2` is connected to a switch. A DHCP server runs on this interface. I want all the traffic from clients connected to `eno2` to be routed through the VPN / tun0.

The basic setup works fine. From hosts attached to `eno2` I can reach hosts in the remote VPN LAN (e.g. `10.123.0.0/24`).

My next goal is routing on `myvpnserver` depending on the source address or interface.

If `myvpnserver` connects to the Internet (e.g. `ftp.debian.org` or VPN host), it should use the default gateway via `eno1`.
If a client attached to `eno2` wants to connect to the same Internet hosts (e.g. `ftp.debian.org`), the traffic should be routed through the VPN / `tun0` instead of `myvpnserver` 's default gateway.

```
// For Incoming Traffic:
If( InputInterface = eno2 ) Then
    default_gateway = 172.17.100.1
Else
    default_gateway = gateway as declared in /etc/network/interfaces
End If
```

I found out **policy-based routing** seems to be the way to go. While "normal" routing is based on the destination only, policy-based routing is said to be able to consider additional aspects like the input interface or source IP range.

What are the steps to take? (I'm on Debian 11 / Bullseye.)

1.) I added a row `1000 vpntunnel` to `/etc/iproute2/rt_tables`.

What's next?
Can you point me to a configuration example?

Thanks a lot for any advice!

Comment: Is myvpnserver doing NAT itself through tun0 (and while at it through eno1 too)? Since it's not needed and should be avoided if the remote VPN peer can be configured adequately, such information simplify understanding of the setup. But then of course other configurations should be provided. eg: the fact that without this NAT various remote routes must be added to various routing equipments' route, not yet talking about policy routing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The next steps to take might be as simple as adding one policy rule and one routing table entry.

You can try:

```
ip route add default via 172.17.100.1 table 1000
ip rule add type unicast iif eno2 table 1000 pref 30000
```

I'm assuming that 172.17.100.1 is the other end of your VPN tunnel.
I used the numerical value of 1000 for the table, but since you added an entry with name "vpntunnel", you could use the name.

Your VPN might already have some configuration setup that could conflict with what I'm suggesting.  The outputs of "`ip rule show`" and "`ip route show table all`" could be useful in the question.  Also, existing iptables configuration could also require a change to the suggested solution.