# change default route for VPN users

Tags: linux, vpn, strongswan, l2tp, libreswan

I have a linux (currently centos 8 but I can change it to anything) server running as l2tp VPN Server which has two network interfaces as below:

NIC1: 192.168.1.4/24 NIC2: 192.168.3.2/24

Default gateway for server is 192.168.1.1 but I want to set 192.168.3.1 as vpn users default gateway. 192.168.3.1 is another router in my network.

I currently use libreswan but I am open to change it to anything that does the job!

Tried to read ipsec.conf file but couldn't find any related line.

Comment: But 192.168.3.1 is in a different subnetwork in 192.168.1.1; it cannot be the default router if it's not in the same subnet, which you define to be the first 24 bit of your address. So, what you want is nonsensical.

Comment: I don't want to 192.168.3.1 be the server default gateway, I want it to be gateway for vpn users. I already have access to 192.168.3.1 and looking for a way to pass the vpn traffic over it.

Comment: so, is 192.168.3.1 in the same subnet as the VPN users are?

Comment: No, it is 192.168.7.0/24 but the point is I want my linux server act as a router! So different subnets won't be a problem, no?

Comment: the default router for any machine is literally the computer within that machine's subnet that allows that machine to go to other subnets. So, a default router inherently must be part of the same network.

Comment: Does your L2TP / libreswan setup create network interfaces on the server?  I'm thinking that maybe a solution similar to https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/725727/route-all-traffic-from-one-interface-default-gateway-through-openvpn-tun0/725778#725778 might be helpful.